# Create button like this in android 2.3.3

Tags: android, button, styles

How can I create a button like this in android 2.3.3 (Eclipse):

[image: button]

Answer (score 1):

You can use HoloEverywhere. This is an open source

https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere

Answer (score 1):

You can implement with `ImageView` for that, you create an image with holo effect and place it as `android:src="@drawable/holo_img"` inside the imageview

Answer (score 0):

Try to create custom button, you can create any shape by coding in xml file for example
here is my code for creating button with round corners

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <shape      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:shape="rectangle">

        <solid   android:color="#FFFDD0"/>

        <corners    android:bottomLeftRadius="8dip"
                    android:topRightRadius="8dip"
                    android:topLeftRadius="8dip"
                    android:bottomRightRadius="8dip"
                    />
        <stroke android:width="1px" android:color="#000000" />

    </shape>
```

change this code according to your requirement.